# Can we have MathJax enabled in Meta?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Some questions on the main site have formulae in titles, and it's difficult to discuss such things in the meta without mutilating the titles. It would be nice to have MathJax enabled on the Meta as well.

Comment: I e-mailed director of community development Robert Cartaino about it, because he has worked with enabling MathJax for other meta: http://meta.hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/132/mathjax-greasemonkey-script

Answer (score 6):

Can someone from SE please revisit this request now that we're out of beta. Signal processing is sufficiently math heavy that it's sometimes required in meta discussions as well. For example, see [this](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1370/should-we-encourage-or-expect-posters-to-adopt-the-current-common-notation-xn) recent question.

Answer (score 2):

Done (after a short hiccup that hopefully didn't inconvenience anyone). We usually do this when we turn MathJax on for the main site, somehow it fell through the cracks - sorry about that :)

It's enabled now, enjoy.

Comment: so let's test it out:  $$\begin{align} X(f) &\triangleq \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x(t) \ e^{-j 2 \pi f t} \ dt \\ \\ x(t) &= \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} X(f) \ e^{+j 2 \pi f t} \ df \\  \end{align} $$ that seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

let's see if it works for an answer:

$$\begin{align} X(f) &\triangleq \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x(t) \ e^{-j 2 \pi f t} \ dt \\ \\ x(t) &= \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} X(f) \ e^{+j 2 \pi f t} \ df \\  \end{align} $$

that seems to work too.

Thank you Tim.