# Can one latexify formulae on Signal Processing meta?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

Yesterday, I did some edit to a post, and by mistake retyped formulae with a  latex syntax.  Signal Processing Meta does not allow latexified math formula yet, see for instance [Can we have MathJax enabled in Meta?](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1212/can-we-have-mathjax-enabled-in-meta). So I wondered if I should uncorrect the corrections, or leave them texified, since:

- I generally am more confident in the interpretation when I read latex formulae,
- the day will come, and we will be ready.

Would you consider writing in latex syntax on Meta an "OK" practice?

Comment: Happily, this question is no longer relevant as MathJax has just been enabled natively! Yay!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose using the same syntax as we would in DSP, but at the same time, hyper-link to something like [Quicklatex](http://quicklatex.com/).

For example [$y = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} x_i \cdot w_i$](http://quicklatex.com/cache3/e7/ql_81f5cc8b86b3505d7e40eb7da51279e7_l3.png).

Or even:

$y = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} x_i \cdot w_i$ ([i.e. this](http://quicklatex.com/cache3/e7/ql_81f5cc8b86b3505d7e40eb7da51279e7_l3.png))

When (and if) the time comes, then the text between the "$" signs could start be rendering properly but until then, a person who would like to see through the "clutter" still gets the rendering option.

Comment: More work possibly, depending on external ressources, but a quite interesting option

Comment: I don't like how the link goes to a new page with just that equation, and such links may get old too. Better use some browser extension like Math Anywhere for Chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/math-anywhere/gebhifiddmaaeecbaiemfpejghjdjmhc

Comment: That's great, although browser specific. Firefox doesn't seem to have an equivalent (?). And less work as you now don't have to copy paste to quicklatex or other service as pointed out by @LaurentDuval earlier.

Comment: I added an answer with a script you can use in Firefox

Answer (score 2):

I tend to be a "native speaker" of most \LaTeX formulae, so I'm OK either way.

Also, as a minimum-energy-solution adherent, I'd tend to leave things as they are. New posts should be done as per the poster's ability and intent: if they're more comfortable and/or the point is made better using MathJax code, then do it that way; if they're more comfortable just referencing the particular question on the main site or it's not really needed for clarity, then do it that way.

Comment: I suspect this  is not only about "things as they are". At the present time, DSP Meta does not allow MathJax. So to formulate a question, I may alter my expression, or formulate it in a less precise or generic way. Should one encourage OP to post "as if" they were talking to latex literates?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Greasemonkey script that will display Latex formulas in DSP Meta using MathJax. You also get the preview in the editor, but it is quite slow. I can't get the script to run in Chrome, but it works in Firefox. For Chrome there is the extension [Math Anywhere](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/math-anywhere/gebhifiddmaaeecbaiemfpejghjdjmhc).

#### Firefox instructions

First install the [Greasemonkey extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/?src=search), then copy-paste the script to a text file and save it locally to `MathJaxForDSPMeta.user.js`. Drag'n'drop the script file to a new page in Firefox. Greasemonkey will prompt to install the script.

#### Script

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           MathJax for meta.dsp.stackexchange.com
// @namespace      Olli Niemitalo
// @description    Insert MathJax into meta.dsp.stackexchange.com
// @include        *meta.dsp.stackexchange.com/*
// @require        //cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full
// @require        /js/mathjax-editing.en.js
// @grant          none
// ==/UserScript==

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = "text/x-mathjax-config";
script.text = 'MathJax.Hub.Config({"HTML-CSS": { preferredFont: "TeX", availableFonts: ["STIX","TeX"], linebreaks: { automatic:true }, EqnChunk: (MathJax.Hub.Browser.isMobile ? 10 : 50) },tex2jax: { inlineMath: [ ["$", "$"], ["\\\\(","\\\\)"] ], displayMath: [ ["$$","$$"], ["\\[", "\\]"] ], processEscapes: true, ignoreClass: "tex2jax_ignore|dno" },TeX: {  noUndefined: { attributes: { mathcolor: "red", mathbackground: "#FFEEEE", mathsize: "90%" } }, Macros: { href: "{}" } }, messageStyle: "none"});';
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Great job. Wasn't thinking about GreaseMonkey at all and this is one of these times its use is very clear.

Comment: Just found this script that enhances the editor when writing long questions/answers, works in Chrome too with Tampermonkey: http://stackapps.com/questions/6864/stackexchange-mathjax-editing-improvements